# Anyway to install ROS-NXT on Trusty?

Tags: ros, nxt-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Ubuntu 14.04.02 Trusty installed, along with ROS INDIGO. But like others over the past years, I too can not get the ROS-NXT to install per the wiki pages. If the NXT has been dropped, please update the wiki pages.

I have the source for the package /stack from Foote source, but can't seem to get them built.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204161/anyway-to-install-ros-nxt-on-trusty?/) by [Mr. Jim](https://answers.ros.org/users/21762/mr.-jim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The nxt package hasn't been released since ROS electric (see wiki header http://wiki.ros.org/nxt), and the wiki documentation doesn't claim indigo support. Check out https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-nxt for latest nxt-related discussion.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mr. Jim](https://answers.ros.org/users/21762/mr.-jim/) on 2015-03-03**:
Thanks for the reply.